# Как получить culture в service?

Tags: c#, windows-service

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании сервиса. Как в сервисе узнать culture? В WinForms и WPF все получается, а вот в сервисе даже ошибку не бьет, а выводит пустое значение.

Comment: Что такое "сгдегку"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26474132/windows-service-unable-to-get-correct-system-culture